# postgresql sequence jump 30 or 33 number with cache equals 1

Tags: postgresql

I used postgresql sequence, and tried to get the nextval from the sequence. I used cache 1 and starting value is 1. Things go well when computer is running. But after I powered off the machine exceptionally, and restart it, I found that "select nextval('patient_seq')" jumped 30 or 33. I used cache 1 for that sequence.
Anybody knows why? How sequence works in postgresq?

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `select nextval('patient_seq')` you're allocating & incrementing even if you don't use it.

I think you're intending to use `select currval('patient_seq')` which would give you the last value allocated by `nextval`.

This would allow you to run a bunch of inserts and then see what the last inserted value was.

Comment: Thanks, Phill.  I found the root cause for this issue. Because postgres preallocated 32 more than the configured cache_value, which is hard coded in its source. When power off, the preallocated numbers will be lost, and will re-allocate another 32 + cache_value numbers.

Comment: More details about this '32' number can be found in this post as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66458412/1799308